# How to check if server is apache in python?

Tags: python, apache

I need some idea to test the server from a link. I do not know where to start

Would be:

```
site = 'example.com'
if(site === Apache)
   print '[ok] Apache - Version:'
else
   print '[No] Is not apache'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html
Send a request, get a response and check the "Server" header.

Comment: Thx, could you give me an example?

Comment: You could use google, you know...
It's first time i've ever done such thing in python and i got 'working' example in 10 minutes.
(Almost) everything is in documentation.

Comment: You can use requests  `requests.head(url).headers["Server"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using requests since it's simple and well documented. And it doesn't return an error like urllib

```
import requests

request = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
if "Apache" in request.headers['server']:
    print "Apache Server found"
else: 
    print "This is no Apache Server"
```

Also see : http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/ for more information

Answer (score 0):

In python 3:

```
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
print(response.headers['Server'])
```

would be the simplest way to get the server header in some cases.
Some sites (like stackoverflow), however, will return 403 error code.